# I'm trying to change permissions with ansible and it's not working well

Tags: linux, automation, ansible, redhat

I have this playbook that is working fine, but not as I need it and I cannot find the problem.
The playbook should allow me to change permissions to a filesystem recursively or else to a particular file.

```yaml
- name: Playbook to change file and directory permissions
  hosts: '{{ target_hosts }}'
  vars:
    PATH: '{{ target_path }}'
    PERMISSIONS: '{{ number }}'
    OWNER: '{{ target_owner }}'
    GROUP: '{{ target_group }}'
  tasks:
    - name: Checking that it is not a system mount point
      fail: 
        msg: "Changing permissions on system fs is not allowed"
      when: PATH in ["/etc", "/var", "/tmp", "/usr", "/", "/opt", "/home", "/boot"]

    - name: Checking if the path is a file or a filesystem
      stat: 
        path: '{{ PATH }}'
      register: path_status

    - name: Applying permissions on the filesystem
      block:
        - name: Report if directory exists 
          debug: 
            msg: "Directory {{ PATH }} is present on the server"
          when: path_status.stat.exists

        - name: Applying permissions recursively
          file: 
            path: '{{ PATH }}'
            mode: '0{{ PERMISSIONS }}'
            owner: '{{ OWNER }}'
            group: '{{ GROUP }}'
            recurse: yes
      when: path_status.stat.isdir is defined and path_status.stat.isdir

    - name: Applying permissions on the file
      block:
        - name: Report if file exists
          debug:
            msg: "File {{ PATH }} is present on the server" 
          when: path_status.stat.exists

        - name: Applying permissions
          file: 
            path: '{{ PATH }}'
            state: file
            mode: '0{{ PERMISSIONS }}'
            owner: '{{ OWNER }}'
            group: '{{ GROUP }}'
      when: path_status.stat.isreg is defined and path_status.stat.isreg
```

The first 2 tasks

- Verify that it is not a system filesystem
- Using the Ansible stat module, I register the path that is being
  passed as a parameter of the PATH variable

When I execute just passing a filesystem like in the following example

```sh
ansible-playbook change_fs_permissions.yml -e "target_hosts=centoslabs target_path=/etc number=755 target_owner=root target_group=testing"
```

the execution ends because it's a system mount point. (What do I expect)

But if I enter something like **/tmp/somefile.txt** as a parameter of the PATH variable, my idea is that the playbook will fail again since it cannot change anything within that filesystem but it does not continue executing and changes the permissions.

They will see that I use the BLOCK module since it seemed to me the best so that if a filesystem is passed to it, it executes those tasks and if it is a file it executes the others.

Can you give me some ideas on how to approach this problem?

Comment: You're checking for `path_status.stat.*isdir*` on both blocks ... that should be `isfile` on the second, no?

Comment: It's true, I didn't realize that. I changed to `path_status.stat.isreg` because the documentation says to indicate if it is a regular file I should put `isreg`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it and it's working now.
What I did was change this part:

```
  - name: Checking that it is not a system mount point
  fail: 
    msg: "Changing permissions on system fs is not allowed"
  when: PATH in ["/etc", "/var", "/tmp", "/usr", "/", "/opt", "/home", "/boot"]
```

For:

```
  - name: Checking that it is not a system mount point
  fail: 
    msg: "Changing permissions on system fs is not allowed"
  when: PATH.split('/')[1] in ["/etc", "/var", "/tmp", "/usr", "/", "/opt", "/home", "/boot"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplify the conditions

```yaml
  when: path_status.stat.isdir is defined and path_status.stat.isdir
  when: path_status.stat.isreg is defined and path_status.stat.isreg
```

Do not test whether the attribute is defined or not and set the default to *false* instead. This will skip the situations when *PATH* is neither a directory nor a regular file.

```yaml
  when: path_status.stat.isdir|default(false)
  when: path_status.stat.isreg|default(false)
```

In this case, you can also omit to test the *PATH* existence because if it does not exist the block will be skipped anyway

```yaml
  when: path_status.stat.exists
```

---

Try this

```yaml
    - name: Applying permissions on the filesystem
      block:
        - name: Report if directory exists
          debug:
            msg: "Directory {{ PATH }} is present on the server"

        - name: Applying permissions recursively
          file:
            path: '{{ PATH }}'
            mode: '0{{ PERMISSIONS }}'
            owner: '{{ OWNER }}'
            group: '{{ GROUP }}'
            recurse: true
      when: path_status.stat.isdir|default(false)

    - name: Applying permissions on the file
      block:
        - name: Report if file exists
          debug:
            msg: "File {{ PATH }} is present on the server"

        - name: Applying permissions
          file:
            path: '{{ PATH }}'
            state: file
            mode: '0{{ PERMISSIONS }}'
            owner: '{{ OWNER }}'
            group: '{{ GROUP }}'
      when: path_status.stat.isreg|default(false)
```

Comment: Hello ! @Vladimir Botka, I tested what you tell me, but it's not working. 
I mean, it's works but I had de same issue if I pass as parameter of `'{{ target_path }}'` something like `/tmp/somefile.txt` change the permissions of somefile.txt when it shouldn't